# jwrapper chokes on META-INF directory

Tags: java, jwrapper

Trying jwrapper on a project, it fails like so:

```
**********************************
*          BUILD FAILED          *
**********************************
** Reason: (see stacktrace below)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-empty directory: META-INF/services
        at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.PackerImpl$DoPack.readFile(PackerImpl.java:546)
        at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.PackerImpl$DoPack.run(PackerImpl.java:492)
        at com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.PackerImpl.pack(PackerImpl.java:99)
        at jwrapper.pack200.Pack200Compressor.compressFileToOutputStream(Pack200Compressor.java:133)
        at jwrapper.archive.Archive.addFileToStream(Archive.java:411)
```

The application jar has this:

```
 1  12-03-2014 16:45   META-INF/services/
13  12-03-2014 16:45   META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver
```

What could the problem be?

The same errors is thrown if running pack200 stand-alone. I don't know what's special about META-INF/services. Many other directories are handled without error.

Update:

Just found unzip has a 'verbose' flag, which reveals this oddity:

```
   0  Stored        0   0% 02-22-2013 13:53 00000000  META-INF/maven/net.mikera/mathz/
   1  Defl:N        3 -200% 12-03-2014 16:45 32d70693  META-INF/services/
```

All the directories are marked 'Stored', except META-INF/services/. However I don't know why or how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be unrelated to jwrapper. The clojure uberjar tool, lein, sometimes builds a jar that is incompatible with pack200. It only happens with certain upstream jars, and certain jdk versions (1.7).

A work-around is to unzip/re-zip the clojure uberjar, which fixes the directory structure. This should be done before invoking jwrapper.